# How to setup gtkmm3 from msys2 on codeblocks

Tags: codeblocks, windows-11, gtkmm3

I want to use gtkmm on Code::Blocks with g++.
I used msys2 to install it.
I checked whether the installation worked with some example code.

```
#include <gtkmm.h>

class MyWindow : public Gtk::Window
{
public:
  MyWindow();
};

MyWindow::MyWindow()
{
  set_title("Basic application");
  set_default_size(200, 200);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  auto app = Gtk::Application::create("org.gtkmm.examples.base");

  return app->make_window_and_run<MyWindow>(argc, argv);
}
```

but it gave me this error.
`fatal error: gtkmm.h: No such file or directory`
I tried putting the pkg-config --cflags and --libs as compiler arguments but it still gave me the same error.

OS: Windows 11.

IDE: Code::Blocks 20.03.

msys2 version: 3.3.6-341.x86_64.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the pkg-config I installed was for use with a Linux OS. I had used
`pacman -S pkg-config` instead of `pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-pkg-config` in the MSYS2 terminal